# Find the equation of a term in function of the second

Tags: number-theory, functions, algebraic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I want to write A(n) in terms of B(n) but nothing seems to work I can find the appropriate pattern.

```
 
n    A(n)    B(n)
1     1       0
1     1       1
2     3       1
3     5       2
4     9       3
5     15      5
6     25      8
7     41      13
8     67      21
```

Comment: Are you sure $A(8)$ is not 67?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $A(8)$ is $67$ and not 61, as in your table, compare 
$$A(n+1)-A(n) \mbox{ with } 2B(n)$$

**Hint 2** $\sum_{k=1}^n A(k+1)-A(k)$ is telecopic. Use
$$\sum_{k=1}^n A(k+1)-A(k)=2 \sum_{k=1}^n B(k)$$

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed 67

Comment: I spent quite a time doing it. I don't get how people can see it so easly

Comment: @MohamedTa I didn't recognize the pattern for $A(n)$, and I saw it was growing fast.... So I looked at its difference sequence, which is a standard trick in this case.

Comment: is there any way to just (A(n) in terms of B(n) or B(n+1) instead of A(n+1):

I thin I get it:  2B(n+1) -1.  Thanks for the hint

Comment: @MohamedTa see the second hint.

Comment: Yeah I got it Thanks